# Proper naming convention for a .NET Delegate type?

Tags: .net, delegates, naming-conventions

By convention classes are often named like nouns, methods like verbs and interfaces like adjectives.

What is the common naming convention for a delegate? Or what's a good way to differentiate its name when delegates are listed among types and other things?

My immediate assumption is to name a delegate more likely an *adjective* because a single method interface can often be replaced with a delegate.

Some thoughts:

```
delegate object ValueExtracting(object container);

delegate object ValueExtractor(object container);

delegate object ValueExtractionHandling(object container);

delegate object ValueExtractionHandler(object container);
```

Answer (score 127, accepted):

Personally I use a couple of different patterns:

`[Task][State]Handler`     - *UITaskFinishedHandler*

`[Event]Handler`           - *ControlLoadedHandler*

`[Function Name]Delegate`  - *DoSomeWorkDelegate* - used when I need to create a delegate for calling a function on a different/new thread

`[Task]Callback`           - *ContainerLoadedCallback*  - used when control A starts an action which control B does most of the work and control A has passed a dependency in to control B (i.e. ControlA may have passed a UI container for ControlB to fill and needs notification to actually show the container)

When you have a project that uses a lot of multi threading or async WCF calls you can end up with a lot of delegates floating around, so it is important to adopt a standard that at least makes sense to you.

Comment: +1 It's a nice convention. I'm also agree with the @Aaronaught answer below where a delegate uses by an event type should have the 'EventHandler' suffix instead of just 'Handler'.

Comment: "[Function Name]Delegate" violates CA1711, unfortunately.  I like to use "[Function Name]Func" or "[Function Name]Action" depending on if it has a return type or not.

Comment: That is probably single most usefull (and shortest) convention I have seen so far. +1 from me. Thanks for sharing @slugster

Comment: The code rules tell you not to suffix any delegate with Delegate https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/code-quality/ca1711-identifiers-should-not-have-incorrect-suffix?view=vs-2017

Comment: @MelbourneDeveloper That's a useful reference but note that it was published for analyzers/compilers/products that were released 6 years after my answer. Also when you have a number of delegates floating around because the tech stack relies heavily on multi-threading and it doesn't provide any built in compile time supports then the *Delegate* suffix is quite useful.

Comment: When the answer was published is irrelevant. Microsoft hasn't explain why you shouldn't suffix delegate types with Delegate, but they are clear about it. It would be good if we could find out why they actively discourage this now.

Comment: @MelbourneDeveloper probably due to them open sourcing a bunch of their code - they want to ensure any contributions are of a very high quality and there's no misunderstanding with type names.

Comment: @MelbourneDeveloper tell that the guys who created the [`RequestDelegate`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.http.requestdelegate?view=aspnetcore-2.2) for asp.net-core ;-]

Answer (score 58):

Microsoft's [Framework Design Guidelines](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/design-guidelines/index) - the naming almanac for me, says [the following](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/design-guidelines/names-of-classes-structs-and-interfaces#names-of-common-types) on the topic:

> √ DO add the suffix "EventHandler" to names of delegates that are used
>   in events.
>   √ DO add the suffix "Callback" to names of delegates other
>   than those used as event handlers.
>   X DO NOT add the suffix "Delegate" to a delegate.

Comment: Funny that MS says 'DO NOT add the suffix "Delegate" to a delegate', but in [this example](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173176.aspx) they have a delegate called `ProcessBookDelegate`...

Comment: @PadawanLondon the same story with [`RequestDelegate`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.http.requestdelegate?view=aspnetcore-2.2) in asp.net-core - so much to consistency and coding conventions. I guess the don't even read their own docs.

Answer (score 19):

Since a delegate is something that performs an action (a verb), the delegate should be named what you would call something that performs that action. Take `Converter<TInput, TOutput>` for example. The verb is **Convert**. The thing that does the converting is called a **converter**, hence the name of the delegate.

Answer (score 6):

This depends on a few things.

If the delegate is going to be used as an event, it should *always* be referred to as an `EventHandler` subtype, for example:

```
public delegate void ValueExtractingEventHandler(object sender,
    ValueExtractingEventArgs e);
```

If it's not an event, then the MS coding guidelines (which I can never seem to find the right copy of on Google) explicitly recommend *against* including words like "delegate" or "handler" in the delegate name, *except* in the special case of `EventHandler` types.

Normally, delegates should be named after *actions*, which would be like `ValueExtracting` (if the delegate happens before the value is extracted) or `ValueExtracted` (after extraction).

The `Func<T1, T2, ..., TResult>` delegate syntax is also becoming more common, but unless you have 4 or more parameters going into it, you don't need to declare your own at all - just use an existing one:

```
object ExtractObject(object source, Func<object, object> extractor);
```

This syntax is best when the delegate is being used as a *closure*.  The delegate itself doesn't have a very interesting name, but the argument is an *agent noun* (extractor, provider, evaluator, selector, etc.)

Most delegate usages fit into one of the above categories, so figure out which one it's being used for choose appropriately.

Answer (score 3):

I never thought about it, mostly because I just use one of the `EventHandler<T>`, `Func<T>`, or `Action<T>` overloads and never bother defining my own. I would probably pick ValueExtractor from those you've listed. This makes it sound more like an object, and when you invoke it you'll be using that object to perform an action. For example:

```
ValueExtractor extractor += Blah;
var value = extractor(data);
```

Additionally, most of the built-in delegates are named like nouns as well. When in doubt, follow the .NET framework.

Answer (score 1):

Based on [`Enumerable.Sum`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb549046.aspx), I'd pass the delegate as a `Func<object, object>` and name the parameter `selector`:

```
void Foo(Func<object, object> selector) ...
```

If you have to make your own delegate for it, I'd go with `ValueExtractor` since that's the most descriptive name for what it does.

Comment: These generic delegates (Action and Func) are fine 95% of cases. There are some cases where they are wildly insufficient though - that is when the delegate has complicated signature AND gets passed around a lot. Basically, what each argument does should be obvious, if it is not, making a named delegate is a good idea.

Answer (score 0):

I would go with ValueExtraction..
I've Never thought why, but I guess because you're storing an operation and it should be a noun..
strictly this is not an operation, I know...

Answer (score 0):

In case of Events (with Delegates) Windows Forms uses following convention:

Delegate:

```
public delegate void MouseEventHandler(object sender, MouseEventArgs e);
```

Event:

```
public event MouseEventHandler MouseClick;
```

Event Listener:

```
this.MouseClick += new System.Windows.Forms.MouseEventHandler(this.Form1_MouseClick);
```