# What is the preferred naming convention for Func<TResult> method parameters?

Tags: c#, lambda, naming-conventions

I admit that this question is subjective but I am interested in the view of the community. I have a cache class that takes a cache loader function of type `Func<TResult>`, which it uses to retrieve a value from the database and store it in cache.

```
public static class Cache
{
    public TResult Get<TResult>(string cacheKey, Func<TResult> cacheLoader) 
    {
        // Implementation
    }
}
```

My question is: **How should I name the function parameter?**

- Should I name it like an object, e.g. `cacheLoader`?
- Should I name it like a method, e.g. `loadResult`?
- Should I explicitly refer to it as a function, e.g. `cacheLoadFunction`? (I don't like this.)

I'm less interested in what I should name *this* particular function parameter and more interested in how you name function parameters in general. What say ye, Stack Overflow community?

Comment: it is a function so you I would name it like any other function.

Comment: @codymanix it is also a variable to make matters worse ;) I prefer Joe's answer.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

There are precedents for using a noun in the Framework, e.g.

```
Enumerable.Average<TSource>(this IEnumerable<TSource> source, Func<TSource, decimal?> selector)

Enumerable.Count<TSource>(this IEnumerable<TSource> source, Func<TSource, bool> predicate)

Enumerable.GroupBy<TSource, TKey, TElement>(this IEnumerable<TSource> source, Func<TSource, TKey> keySelector, Func<TSource, TElement> elementSelector)

ConcurrentDictionary<TKey,TValue>.GetOrAdd(TKey key, 
            Func<TKey, TValue> valueFactory);
```

The noun is often an appropriate verb with [an agentive suffix](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Agentive_ending).

In your example I would use something like `loader` or possibly `valueFactory`.  I personally don't like `cacheLoader` because presumably it's the caller rather than the delegate that does the work of inserting in the cache.

Comment: While I like @Reed's idea of naming it like a method, so that calling it looks more natural, framework precedent is the trump card in my opinion.

Comment: I'll speak up against the framework  It was not written to be an example to follow. It was written by a large number of developers to meet corporate deadlines. It's often not readable/clean.

Answer (score 8):

I like to name it like a method so that when you invoke it, like this:

```
loadResult(result);
```

it looks like an ordinary method call but the casing indicates that it is a variable, so both pieces of information are conveyed.

You can append a suffix like `Method` or `Delegate` or `Lambda` but those often just make it verbose without adding clarity.  It can depend on the situation and your coding standards, and of course your preferences.

Comment: I sort of like this logic, except for one thing.  The argument name should be chosen to make the purpose clear to the caller, not necessarily to the implementer of the method...

Comment: @Reed: You're right, that's a conflict of interest that argues in the favor of the caller.  If a library exposes a public API the naming of parameters is sacred.  That's an example of coding standards.

Comment: Yeah, it seems like the parameter name should communicate to the caller "pass in a method that will do this". Whether the caller implements the method or finds one, he needs to know what it ought to do.

Answer (score 6):

I typically actually use the word *delegate* in my naming, to make it obvious that this parameter is receiving a delegate.  For example, I'd potentially name the above:

```
public static class Cache
{
    public TResult Get<TResult>(string cacheKey, Func<TResult> cacheLoadingDelegate) 
    {
        // Implementation
    }
}
```

I do this specifically to avoid confusion from the suggested naming in the question.  `cacheLoader` sounds too much like an object, and `loadResult` like an object/type (the result itself).  I also don't personally like using `function` or `method`, as a delegate is not actually a function, but rather a delegate - a type that references a function.

Comment: The answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/25993838/661933) says MS is against that convention.