# Code conventions for Action and Func

Tags: c#, naming-conventions

Are there any coding conventions for using `Action` and `Func` types? Namely, I am curious whether they should have the first letter in upper case when used as a parameter in a method (`Action someAction` or `Action SomeAction`).

Comment: Do the same as you do with all other types. What would the special treatment be for?

Comment: FWIW, I use standard parameter conventions, but I often use a parameter name which implies action, e.g. "parentMutator", "stateGetter", etc.

Comment: @Jon It just looks strange call a method like this: someAction(something). It reminds me of Java conventions.

Comment: @Andrew: It looks strange if you are not yet familiar with functional programming concepts. I don't think it would look strange to e.g. any JavaScript developer. But in any case, your code, your conventions.

Comment: Also see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6061517/what-is-the-preferred-naming-convention-for-functresult-method-parameters?rq=1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would think that they would follow the same convention as any parameter being passed to a method.  In C#, it seems that the most common convention for a method parameter is Camel case.  So, I would stick with that for Actions and Funcs as well.